# Content window on marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I try this code for plotting data on google map and I plot it successfully currently there is 2 marker when i click on marker then content window is open but second marker content window is not open

this is the result on console

```
{"response":[["B9","5",27.13197”,”34.95 "],["L330","5",”27.06688”,”34.864"]}"
```

image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGt1X.png)

when i click on second marker then content window not open

**Here is my code :**

```
success: function (result) {


                    var d = JSON.parse(result.d).response;

                    console.log(JSON.parse(result.d).response);

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.d));

                    $("#tabledata").empty();
                    if (d.length > 0) {
                        $("#tabledata").append(
      "<thead><tr><th>RegNo</th><th>Status</th><th>Longitude</th><th>Latitude</th></tr></thead>");

                        for (var i = 0; i < d.length - 1; i++) {
                            if (d[i] !== null) {
                                $("#tabledata").append("<tbody><tr><td>" +
                           d[i][0] + "</td> <td>" +
                           d[i][1] + "</td> <td>" +
                           d[i][2] + "</td> <td>" +
                           d[i][3] + "</td></tr></tbody>");
                                Status = d[i][2];
                                debugger;
                                RegNo = d[i][0];
                                latit = d[i][4];
                                longi = d[i][3];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#tabledata").hide();
                    }

                    alert(d.length);
                    var map;
                    //var markers;
                    debugger;
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.0895898, 67.0998546);
                    debugger;
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 8,
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    debugger;
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                    debugger;

                    debugger;
                    for (i = 0; i < d.length - 1; i++) {
                        var data = d[i]
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(d[i][4], d[i][3]);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            map: map,
                            title: 'Click me'

                        });
                    }
                        debugger;
                        for (i = 0; i < d.length - 1; i++){
                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: 'RegNo:' + d[i][0] + '<br>Status:' + d[i][2] + '<br>Lat:' + d[i][4] + 'Long:' + d[i][3]
                            });
                        }
                            debugger;
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                                infowindow.open(map, marker, data);
                            });
                        }
```

Comment: What is the variable `d`?  You probably need to change `i < d.length - 1;` to `i < d.length;` unless you're deliberately wanting to exclude the last item in that array.

Comment: d is something i declare and i populate table through jquery for (i = 0; i < d.length -1; i++) { @duncan

Comment: @duncan check updated please complete code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line here:

```
infowindow.open(marker, data, map);
```

The [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow) open function takes 1 or 2 arguments, and it should be like this:

```
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```